# Bash: option menu no wait for enter

Tags: bash

I have an options menu function:

```
function()
{
echo "1    Option 1"
echo "2    Option 2"
echo "3    Option 3"
echo "q    Exit"
read -p "Select 1-3 ή \"q\" to quit: " i    
case "$i" in
    1)
    echo "option 1"
    echo;;
    2)   
    echo "option 2"
    echo;;

    3) 
    echo "option 3"
    echo;;

    q) echo -e "\033[01;33mexit!!!\033[39m"
    sleep 1
    clear
    exit ;;
     *)
        echo "Unknown command"
        read -s -n 1 -p "Press any key to continue…"
        echo
esac
}
while: 
do function
done
```

The above works fine, but need to press enter after I input the number before the command run. Is there any way to immediately run the command when I press the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the answer right in your sample code (in the second `read`).  You want to take advantage of `bash`'s `read -n 1` capability (note, this is not POSIX compliant, so it won't reliably work in `/bin/sh` unless that happens to map to `bash`):

```
read -n 1 -p "Select 1-3 ή \"q\" to quit: " i
```

Comment: I tried that before, but seems that I had a typo because I get error. I tried now again and it works. Thanks!